# Use of a preposition of a indirect verb with more than one object

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know the correct use of a preposition of a indirect verb when there is more than one object. Do I need to repeat the preposition in that case? For exemple:

> To get the result we resort **to** Sperner's lemma, **to** Brouwer's fixed-point theorem
>   and **to** some results of topology and analysis of functions.

Sorry if the question is trivial. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's good style to use the same preposition for all three, but it's not required.  However the verb "require" generally takes the preposition "to" in this context.

Comment: @Andrew Then must I use only one preposition?

Comment: @StoneyB er, yeah.  That's what I meant  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally considered good *style* to use the same preposition when making lists of things, but it's not a grammar rule.  For example:

> Tomorrow we plan to go to the museum, to the library, and to the shopping district.

Of course it's possible to mix up different prepositions, but then it's not really a "list" of similar things.

> Tomorrow we plan to go to the museum, on the train, with our friends.

It may be helpful to memorize English verbs as verb-preposition *pairs*, since the meaning can change depending on which preposition is used.  For this reason it's difficult to think of an example where you can mix prepositions but still have all of the objects relate to the verb in the same way.

For example, in the above sentence what other preposition would you use other than "to"?  "Resort to" is (more or less) the only verb-preposition pair that works.